# CSS Styling goes wrong on refresh of page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a local version and version that is hosted by IIS onto a server.

When i click the link to load up my page all the styling is fine and it suppost to be where it is:

[image]

I choose all my data and submit my page which runs this C# code.

```
newRecord.NumberofItems = Convert.ToInt32(totalitems);

cPostFunctions test = new cPostFunctions();

test.InsertNewRecord(newRecord);

//Add Message
Response.Write("<script langauge=\"javascript\">alert(\"Entry Submitted\");</script>");

Page_EntrySubmitted(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

In the Page_EntrySubmitted method all it does is set the Textboxes, Dropdowns and labels to NULL.

When the page refreshes after the alert this happens:

[image]

All my styles are getting pulled through but it seems as it is stretching everything.

**THIS ONLY HAPPENS ON THE SERVER NOT MY LOCAL VERSION**

Comment: Can you share a link to your server so that we can try debugging it?

Comment: You can share full code. It might be missing some css files